# Stuck In Emergency After Trying To Mount Drive

Tags: boot, mount, steam, recovery-mode

Was following this guide on how to mount a drive for installing steam games but then after a restart got stuck in emergency mode.

https://www.instructables.com/id/Assigning-Multiple-Drives-to-Steam-on-Linux/

Am new to Linux so am totally confused as to what I'm supposed to do now.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I am not sure what you mean by 'emergency mode'. Can you please clarify?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dhyo.jpg

This is the screen I'm stuck in

Comment: I guess you just completed **Step 5: Restart and See If It Worked** Undo your modifications in `/etc/fstab` or in case you added new lines, comment them out with **#** at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I edit the fstab file? A live usb and trying to edit it from emergency mode gives me "permission denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took hours of research but I finally found the solution.

When boot into emergency mode, press `enter` to enter maintenance.

You'll already be root and have read write permission so just type `vi /etc/fstab` to edit the fstab file which is what decides what gets mounted in boot I think.
Delete your changes by using the `arrow keys` to go down to where you made the change, and use the `delete` button to remove the changes.

After that, type `:wq` which saves the changes and finally type `reboot`

Done!

By the way, I think the guide made my system fail because the name of my drive had a space in it. System76 recommends not adding spaces to drive names so maybe that's the case.

Comment: `vi` / `vim` has a larger learning curve than `nano`